# SQL query with if inside

Tags: php, sql

I have search form with 2 drop boxes. Lets say `products` and `recipe_type`.
If the user choose both dropboxes my query works just fine.
But if someone decide to search only for product the query wont work.

How this should be done?

The query is:

```
SELECT 
  receitas.id, 
  receitas.titulo, 
  receitas.img_small, 
  receitas.tempo, 
  receitas.dificuldade, 
  receitas.pessoas, 
  id_tipo.id_tipo, 
  id_tipo.id_receita, 
  tipo.id_t, 
  produtos.id_p, 
  produtos.nome,  
  id_produto.id_receita, 
  id_produto.id_produto 
FROM 
  receitas, id_tipo, tipo, produtos, id_produto 
WHERE 
  tipo.id_t = %s 
AND produtos.id_p = %s 
AND receitas.id = id_tipo.id_receita  
AND id_tipo.id_tipo = tipo.id_t 
AND receitas.id = id_produto.id_receita 
AND id_produto.id_produto = produtos.id_p
```

anyone to help me ?

Comment: Can you show us your full code ?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What do the variables contain, when they are not specified? NULL? An empty string? Here is an example for empty strings:

```
SELECT 
  receitas.id, 
  receitas.titulo, 
  receitas.img_small, 
  receitas.tempo, 
  receitas.dificuldade, 
  receitas.pessoas, 
  id_tipo.id_tipo, 
  id_tipo.id_receita, 
  tipo.id_t, 
  produtos.id_p, 
  produtos.nome,  
  id_produto.id_receita, 
  id_produto.id_produto 
FROM 
  receitas, id_tipo, tipo, produtos, id_produto 
WHERE 
  (tipo.id_t = %s OR %s = '')
AND (produtos.id_p = %s OR %s = '')
AND receitas.id = id_tipo.id_receita  
AND id_tipo.id_tipo = tipo.id_t 
AND receitas.id = id_produto.id_receita 
AND id_produto.id_produto = produtos.id_p
```

Comment: when they are not specified the contain can be anything. can be 0. the thing is if the variable has anything inside i got a few results, if the variable is empty i should have receive ALL results based on the rest of the query. don't know if i'm explaining myself well..

Comment: No, when you look for tipo 100, the variable will contain '100'. When you don't look for a certain tipo, then the variable won't contain 100. Right? What I am showing you is that you should check your variables wether they are empty. Anyhow %s looks like php not SQL. So how do you replace them? With a mere string operation like printf? Then you can even use your own statement and fill the variable with "tipo.id_t" in case it's empty. This will result in `WHERE tipo.id_t = tipo.id_t`, so you get all tipos.